# Implement Count inversion using merge sort algorithm in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need to implement the count inversion algorithm for a homework but i couldn't figure out what is the problem in my code.Our professor asked us to implement count inversion in c++(Which i didn't work with it much) without using any C++ libraries only i could include `<iostream>` and use std only for output (`cout<<`) and that's it, also he gave us this piece here :

```
 void count_inversion(int a[],int n){
    count_inversion(a, n / 2);
    count_inversion(a + (n / 2), n / 2);
    count_inversion_merge(a, n / 2, n);
  }
```

and said we should implement the `count_inversion_merge` function and use this piece as a hint.
So i tried to adapt the code a little to work but still have no luck.

Here is my code :

```
 int count_inversion_merge(int array[], int mid, int n) {
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            if (j == n || (i < mid && array[i] < array[j])) {
                b[k] = array[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                b[k] = array[j];
                j++;
                inversion++;
            }
        }

    }
```

My First input `int a[] ={ 2, 4, 1, 3, 5 };` should return 3 but it returns 5
and my second output should be 5 and i get 5. I hope that someone could point out where is my error.

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: i get strange outputs for value of indexs in array also it jumping into the else part every time.

Comment: For a small example input you should be able to perform the algorithm by hand (if not: you need to understand the algorithm before you can try to fix problems) and than compare what you did by hand with the debugging.

Comment: I fully understand the algorithm.it's pretty easy actually,but i really hate c++

Comment: check this out. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/

Comment: _i could include <iostream> and use std only for output_ YAIT (yet another incompetent teacher)

Comment: @manni66 actually he is pretty good,i understood how the algorithm works but i think the implementation problem is mine.

Comment: _i really hate c++_ you are not allowed to use C++, so _he is pretty good_ is false!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic idea is right, but there 2 problems in your code. One is conceptual, another is in code.

1. In the else block of merge step, you are increasing the inversion by one. Instead, you should increase it by how many values you have in the left part. So in else block you should use, `inversion += mid-i;` instead of `inversion++;` Because, you need to actually count the number of swaps required. At this point, for the value  of `array[j]`, you have `mid - i` (rest of left array) number of elements which were actually needed to swap corresponding to `array[j]`. That means, if you would use bubble sort, you would need to swap all the rest elements in left array (`mid-i`) with this single value (`array[j]`). So, for this `array[j]` you should increase number of elements rest in the left sub-array.
2. In the recursive calling of `count_inversion`, you are missing some values in every call. e.g. lets say `n=5`. Then you are using `5/2 = 2` at left and `5/2 = 2` at right. But you are missing the last element at the right side. You can solve it by using as following in your second recursive call. Here, you should use the rest of the length you used from first call.

   `count_inversion(a + (n / 2), n - n / 2);`

A little modified code from yours with fixes: https://ideone.com/raKD7T

Comment: Thanks @dipal i understand the second point perfectly. In my case it would work for an even number of elements but if the elements number is odd i will not get the last element,But i don't understand the 1st part could you edit your answer and add more explication ?sure think i will mark your answer as right

Comment: I have tried to explain, but for more detailed explanation you could the follow the @H'H s link of geeksforgeeks. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/

Comment: Thanks for your help